# Bootstrap Dropdown Menu doesn't work on wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I made an html template and want to convert this into WordPress. They are all working good, only the Bootstrap dropdown is not working.

Bootstrap says to use this CDNS. But I use (jquery-3.2.1) and (bootstrap.min.js) directly and I use proper.js (cdn). Normally it works perfectly, but when I enqueue this on Function.php like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js', array('jquery'), 1.12.0, true);
```

WordPress shows an Error and my dropdown doesn't work.

Comment: Why don't you try using Bootstrap NavWalker? https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

Comment: it would be easier to troubleshoot for other members if you add the error that is generated in your Original Post by editing it.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the following tutorial to use Bootstrap in Wordpress Admin Panel

https://rushfrisby.com/using-bootstrap-in-wordpress-admin-panel/

I hope this can help you, for me was good.